# Using complex update selectors for atomic operations in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Suppose you are making a chatroom app where users can set a nickname, but the nickname must be unique to the chatroom. I have implemented this with a method something like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  setNickname: function( nickname ) {
    check( nickname, String );

    if ( ! this.userId ) { /* throw error */ }

    var chatroom = Chatroom.collection.findOne({
      'users._id': this.userId
    });

    if ( _.findWhere( chatroom.users, { nickname: nickname } ) ) { /* throw error */ }

    Chatroom.collection.update({
      'users._id': this.userId,
    }, {
      $set: {
        'users.$.nickname': nickname
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This feels clunky and I'm wondering if there could be a concurrency issue with the validation logic being separate from the query like this. I was thinking that I could move this logic into the query itself with something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  setNickname: function( nickname ) {
    check( nickname, String );

    if ( ! this.userId ) { /* throw error */ }

    Chatroom.collection.update({
      'users._id': this.userId,
      'users.nickname': {
        $ne: nickname
      }
    }, {
      $set: {
        'users.$.nickname': nickname
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I'm fairly new to MongoDB, so I'm not sure which approach is better. Both ways seem to work the same, but I feel like the first way could allow identical nicknames if two users tried to set the same nickname at the same time.

So basically, should I use complex update selectors to ensure that operations like these are atomic?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to set a unique index in mongodb on both the nickname and the chatroom id. That would prevent inserts or updates that would violate that index. You'd have to catch the errors in your callback if you attempt to insert a nickname that currently exists.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Comment: Here's a quote from another page on the MongoDB docs: "The unique constraint applies to separate documents in the collection. That is, the unique index prevents separate documents from having the same value for the indexed key, but the index does not prevent a document from having multiple elements or embedded documents in an indexed array from having the same value." So since I am denormalizing the user memberships as embedded array elements on the chatroom documents, wouldn't that mean that the unique index won't work?

Comment: Do you mean you'll have one document per chatroom? Can you update your question with a schema example?